# threadpools - boss/worker vs peer (workcrew) models

Tags: c, multithreading, design-patterns, pthreads, threadpool

I'm aiming to use a threadpool with pthreads and am trying to choose between these two models of threading and it seems to me that the peer model is more suitable when working with fixed input, whereas the boss/worker model is better for dynamically changing work items. However, I'm a little unsure of how exactly to get the peer model to work with a threadpool.

I have a number of tasks that all need to be performed on the same data set. Here's some simple psuedocode for how I would look at tackling this:

```
data = [0 ... 999]
data_index = 0
data_size = 1000

tasks = [0 ... 99]
task_index = 0    

threads = [0 ... 31]

thread_function()
{
    while (true)
    {
        index = data_index++ (using atomics)
        if index > data_size
        {
            sync

            if thread_index == 0
            {
                data_index = 0
                task_index++
                sync
            }
            else
            {
                sync
            }
            continue
        }

        tasks[task_index](data[index])
    }
}
```

(Firstly, it seems like there should be a way of making this use just one synchronisation point, but I'm not sure whether that's possible?)

The above code seems like it will work well for the case where the the tasks are known in advance, though I guess a threadpool is unnecessary for this particular problem. However even if the data items are still predefined across all tasks, if the tasks are not known in advance, it seems like the boss/worker model is better suited? Is it possible to use the boss/worker model but still allow the tasks to be picked up by the threads themselves (as above), where the boss essentially suspends itself until all tasks are complete? (Maybe this is still termed the peer model?)

Final question is regarding the synchronisation, barrier or condition variable and why?

If anyone can make any suggestions as to how better to approach this problem or even to poke holes in any of my assumptions, that would be great? Unfortunately I'm restricted from using a more higher-level library such as tbb for tackling this.

Edit: I should point out in case this isn't clear, each task needs to be completed in it's entirety before moving onto the next.

Comment: So all threads execute the same task on a different item until the data is finished, and then synchronize and pass to the next task?

Comment: That's correct. There's no exchange of data between items or between tasks, everything can be treated as independent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by your description here, hope the below is relevant.

I always looked at this pattern and found it very useful: The "boss" is responsible for detecting work and dispatching it to a worker pool based on some algorithm, from that time on, the worker is independent.

In this scenario, the worker is always waiting for work, not aware of any other instance, process requests and when it finishes, may trigger a notification of completion. 
This has the advantage of good separation between the work itself and the algorithm that balance between the threads.

The other option is for the "boss" to maintain a pool of work items, and the workers to always pick them up as soon as they are free. But I guess this is more complex to implement and requires a larger amount of synchronization. I do not see the benefit of this second approach over the previous one.

Control logic and worker state is maintained by the "boss" in both scenarios.
As the paralleled work is done on a task, the "boss" "object" is handling a task, in a simple implementation, this "boss" blocks until a task is finished, allowing to call the next "boss" in line.

Regarding the Sync, unless I'm missing here something, you only need to sync once for all the workers to finish and this sync is done at the "boss" where the workers just send notifications that they finished.